Is it possible to create Android activity from JNI?
My app is C++, it creates a JNI JVM (raw JVM, with class path to some of my .class files).
The JVM above is rather a core Java Virtual Machine without knowing about android.
How to add class path to Android SDK to do something like:
import android.content.Intent;

in my .java files?
Those imports are to use some of classes eg. android.content.Intent, etc. to create some activities.
With just C++, JNI JVM, Android SDK, and no Android Studio, is it possible to create MainActivity for the app?
Edit:
I found the way to add android.jar in the SDK to class path, but a new problem is android.content.Context is abstract and can't be instantiated to use the method .startActivity in it.

Let me get this right: you start an actual honest-to-god JVM from your C++ app on Android? Do you ship that JVM with your app? If so, then I'm pretty certain you won't be able to use any of the Android APIs from that Java VM, as it won't know anything about Android, even if you imported the right jars (which don't exist).

Android is an operating system. It is not a library. Is your intention to run the entire Android OS, or a stripped-down version, in your C++ program, such as via virtualization? If not, then the answer to "is it possible to create MainActivity for the app" is no, if you expect MainActivity to be an Android Activity with a user interface, etc.

@JoachimSauer it's just JNI JVM: JNI_CreateJavaVM

@CommonsWare it's app, not entire OS; and the intention is to create MainActivity with UI

And you successfully call JNI_CreateJavaVM in your app on Android? Because as far as I know that method is not provided by the Android JNI implementation (and the headers don't provide it).

my app is compiled by Clang in Termux, and Termux seems having jni.h by default, and that JNI_CreateJavaVM is working

You've probably seen but just to make sure: https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/pull/7227#issuecomment-893022283

@MorrisonChang i found NativeActivity but it's quite hard to make UI compared to XML: https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_na

All of the XML / Android View stuff is on the Java/Kotlin side. NativeActivity is just a shim for anyone doing their own rendering (games/third-party GUI/OpenGL ES stuff) in C/C++.

If you want your application to be native-first, you can use a GameActivity (or the more older NativeActivity) for your main activity.
If you want to add screens with native UI controls, the easiest way forward is to add a Java/Kotlin activity and start it from your native activity with JNI. You can pass results back and forth by embedding it in the Intent you use to start it, or receive back from onActivityResult, or simply by setting some shared variables.
